# How to I obtain a web applciation performance metrics through browser extension?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, firefox-addon, performance-testing, database-performance

I need to be able to obtain performance metrics such as loading times, REST Calls time through a google extension and mozilla firefox add-on.

The challenge is to get the extension itself. I can't seem to be able to obtain an extension  having those functionality on both google extension and mozilla firefox add-on.

Another challenge is that the data obtained from the performance metrics should be exported so as to be put in a structured database.

Anyone know any extension/add-on with those requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find such extension, in particular storing the results into the database will not be possible at all as extensions can only access limited subset of browser functionality, so called [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox).

So instead of looking for an extension I would recommend investigating [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)

The output of the API can be converted into i.e. [JSON object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)  using [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) function

[image]

JSON is some kind of universal data interchange format so databases either can consume it directly or you can convert it into whatever you want.

If you're looking for a way to automate everything you can consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) tool as an unified testing solution:

- browser automation is being provided via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)
- database connectivity is implemented via [JDBC Connection Configuration and JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) elements

JMeter by nature is a load testing tool so you can combine the above steps which check client-side performance with the backend performance test.